# Cannot show Table View data in a simple Times Table App

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a simple Times Table App (for numbers 1-9) in Swift) using a slider and a Table View. I am managing to make the slider work and an array to be created for each number that is selected with the slider and although the array is shown on the console. I cannot get the numbers to appear on the Table View. Can you please help me and tell me what am I missing?

Here is what I have written so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sliderValue: UISlider!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 9
    }

    @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider) {
        sender.setValue(Float(lroundf(sliderValue.value)), animated: true)

        print(sliderValue)

        var cellContent = [String]()

        for var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1 {
            cellContent.append(String(i * Int(sliderValue.value)))
        }

        print(cellContent)

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

            cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've supplied does not actually refer to any tableView nor set up the tableView's delegate and dataSource. Furthermore your class adhere to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol but actually implements several `UITableViewDataSource` functions, which probably won't be of much use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's quite a lot in the code you've supplied that doesn't make all that much sense. I've mentioned some of it in my comment above but you've also nested what looks like a tableViewDataSource-function into your sliderMoved function. The whole array thing looks rather flakey as well as the proposed cell-count does not actually consider the size of the array. I think you *probably* want something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var valueSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    private var cellContent = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider) {
        sender.setValue(Float(lroundf(valueSlider.value)), animated: true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // TableViewDataSource

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 9
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell") // Must exist with the same identifier in your storyboard
        cell.textLabel?.text = valueStringForIndex(indexPath.row)

        return cell
    }

    // Private functions

    private func valueStringForIndex(index: Int) -> String {
        return "\(index * Int(valueSlider.value))"
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all I would to thank you for your quick reply. Well, I was almost sure that I could be writing something wrong, as I have recently started learning swift and what I am doing is trying to apply the things I'm learning from a course that I'm taking online and trying to figure a few things out myself at the same time. That said, I know that I nested that method inside the other, but I was just trying to make the code work, and that was thought at the moment I posted the question. Thank you a lot for the answer, it is working, although I'm still trying to understand how a few things work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating cellContent array as a instance variable and the following code may work. Check it once.

```
var cellContent = [String]()
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 9
}

@IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider) {
    sender.setValue(Float(lroundf(sliderValue.value)), animated: true)

    print(sliderValue)



    for var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1 {
        cellContent.append(String(i * Int(sliderValue.value)))
    }

    print(cellContent)

    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: I had already thought of that and tried it before posting my question (it was also a recommendation from Xcode). But actually, it's creating a much bigger problem once I try to run the code and it crashes the app. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly an answer to your question ->

Depending on how you want the table displayed, a UICollectionView may be a great fit for this application.  Very similar to UITableView to implement but with boxes and columns of data, may be simpler to format (and changing the slider could add some fun animation when the collection view updates).

The sample UIViewController below demonstrates using a UICollectionView.  In the storyboard, I simply:

- Added a UISlider, UICollectionView, and UILabel and created outlets in MultiplicationTableViewController
- In the UICollectionView default cell I gave it the reuseIdentifier "numberCell", and added a label (to hold the product)
- Made the MultiplicationTableViewController the dataSource and delegate for the UICollectionView

**CODE:**

```
import UIKit

class MultiplicationTableViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var timesTableCollectionView: UICollectionView!
  @IBOutlet weak var numberSlider: UISlider!
  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

  var products = [Int]()   //array to hold the computed value for each cell in the collectionView

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.viewRotated), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)  //register for rotation notifications
    products = createTableOfValues()             //populate products with initial values
    label.text = "\(Int(numberSlider.value)) x \(Int(numberSlider.value))"
  }

  @IBAction func sliderUpdated(sender: UISlider) {
    sender.value = Float(Int(sender.value))      //make the slider stop only on whole numbers
    label.text = "\(Int(sender.value)) x \(Int(sender.value))"
    products = createTableOfValues()             //create the new table values
    timesTableCollectionView.reloadData()        //tell the collectionView to read the new data and refresh itself
  }

  func createTableOfValues() -> [Int] {
    var prod = [Int]()                           //temp array to hold the generated products
    for row in 0...Int(numberSlider.value) {     //iterate from row 0 (header) to
      var columns = [Int]()                      //temp array to build column products
      for column in 0...Int(numberSlider.value) {//iterate through each column, including column 0 (header)
        if column == 0 {
          columns.append(row)
        } else if row == 0 {
          columns.append(column)
        } else {
          columns.append(column * row)
        }
      }
      prod.appendContentsOf(columns)             //add the current row of products to the temp array
    }
    return prod
  }

  func viewRotated() {
    timesTableCollectionView.reloadData()        //called to force collectionView to recalc (basically to get new cell sizes
  }
}

extension MultiplicationTableViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

  func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1                                    //required for UICollectionViewDataSource
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(numberSlider.value + 1) * Int(numberSlider.value + 1)   //tells the UICollectionView how many cells to draw (the number on the slider, plus header rows)
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("numberCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)   //get an existing cell if it exists
    if cell.frame.origin.y == 0.0 || cell.frame.origin.x == 0.0 {     //if the cell is at the top or left of the collectionView
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    } else {
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()                     //If not, reset the color (required because cells are reused
    }
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    let numberItem = cell.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel               //get a reference to the label in the current cell
    numberItem?.text = String(products[indexPath.row])               //get the value generated earlier for this particular cell
    return cell
  }
}

extension MultiplicationTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let columns = CGFloat(numberSlider.value + 1)                       //get the number of columns - slider value + 1 for header
    let width = timesTableCollectionView.bounds.width / columns         //divide the width of the collectionView by the number of columns
    return CGSizeMake(width, width)                                     //use width value to make the cell a square
  }
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: As I mentioned on another comment, I am new to swift and making ios apps, so every new and/or different way of making something is always interesting.
I would surely like to see how it could be implemented differently, so you are more than welcome to provide the code or resources or whatever you think would help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I will post the project to gitHub later if you want to look at it further.